# Fong's Causal Theories: Is he also describing a Monad structure? Is the causal category also a bimonad?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

Fong's paper [Causal Theories: A Categorical Perspective on Bayesian Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6201) talks about causal theories.  He describes words of random variables at the top of page 42:

> For the objects of CG we take the set N V of functions from V to the
>   natural numbers. These may be considered collections of elements of
>   the set of variables V , allowing multiplicities, and we shall often
>   just write these as strings w of elements of V . Here the order of the
>   symbols in the string is irrelevant, and we write Ø for empty string,
>   which corresponds to the zero map of N V . We view these objects as
>   the variables of the causal theory, and we further call the objects
>   which are collections consisting of just one instance of a single
>   element of V the atomic variables of the causal theory.

Is he not just describing something like the List monad?  A single element of V, the atomic variable, is the unit map $\mu : 1_C \rightarrow T$?

He explicitly states that objects have a comonoid map for copying.  I get the feeling this causal category is a bimonad.  Is this correct?

Some supporting evidence includes the following.  This is taken from [Coecke's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0608035.pdf), section 1.5.1.

> Recall from [31] that the internal commutative (co)monoid structures
>   over an object X in a monoidal category C are in one-to-one
>   correspondence with commutative (co)monad structures on the functor X
>   ⊗ − : C → C .

That functor is a comonad, according to the same paper.

So, Fong describes a comonoid, which has an associated comonad and I am pointing out the monad structure.

If it works, please describe the interaction of the monad and comonad (mixed distributive law?).  I think Fong's examples are all on SET.  So the Monad and Comonad would be on SET.

Note:
A bimonad is both a Monad and a comonad.

"There's a relationship between the monad structure and the comonad structure, or more exactly a mixed distributive law between them. In the terminology that some people use, this makes the monad into a "bimonad"."

Comment: It's hard to tell what a category is, or whether something is a monad on it, without knowing what the morphisms might be. Would you please describe the morphisms? Also, it wouldn't hurt if in the first quote you used LaTeX, as I don't quite understand what the "N V" thing is supposed to be.

Comment: But no, it doesn't sound like the list monad. It rather sounds like the multiset monad.